# Suricata installation on top of an ELK stack advice?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I've created a ELK stack for log collection using logstash-forwarders installed on a range of different linux machines and this is working really well.

I am now looking at installing suricata onto the main ELK stack to start using the IDS/IPS features

My first question is that I just need to install suricata onto the main ELK box and change the conf files on this box plus the logtash-forwarders, so suricata only needs to be installed on one box?

Secondly, I'm attempting to change the conf files to allow for suricata so I've listed out my conf files for logstash and the logstash forwarder below

The file 13-suricata.conf is my attempt to bring this into the logstash conf files but I'm not sure if this is the right method and I not sure what to do with the logstash-forwarder conf even?

Any help would be amazing

```
/etc/logstash/conf.d$ ls 
01-lumberjack-input.conf  11-sshlog.conf  13-suricata.conf
10-syslog.conf            12-apache.conf  30-lumberjack-output.conf
```

01-lumberjack-input.conf

```
input   {
  lumberjack    {
    port => 5000
    type => "logs"
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
  }

}
```

10-syslog.conf

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {

```
grok {
  match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
  add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
  add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
}
syslog_pri { }
date {
  match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
}
```

}
}

11-sshlog.conf

```
filter {
if [type] == "sshlog" {
  grok {
    type => "sshlog"
    match => {"message" => "Failed password for (invalid user |)%{USERNAME:username} from %{IP:src_ip} port %{BASE10NUM:port} ssh2"}
    add_tag => "ssh_brute_force_attack"
  }

  grok {
    type => "sshlog"
    match => {"message" => "Accepted password for %{USERNAME:username} from %{IP:src_ip} port %{BASE10NUM:port} ssh2"}
    add_tag => "ssh_sucessful_login"
  }

  geoip {
    source => "src_ip"
  }
}
}
```

12-apache.conf

```
filter {
  if [type] == "apache-access" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
  }
}
```

13-suricata.conf

```
    filter {
      if [type] == "SuricataIDPS" {
        date {
          match => [ "timestamp", "ISO8601" ]
        }
        ruby {
          code => "if event['event_type'] == 'fileinfo'; event['fileinfo']['type']=event['fileinfo']['magic'].to_s.split(',')[0]; end;"
        }
      }

  if [src_ip]  {
    geoip {
      source => "src_ip"
      target => "geoip"
      #database => "/opt/logstash/vendor/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat"
      add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
      add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
    }
    mutate {
      convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float" ]
    }
    if ![geoip.ip] {
      if [dest_ip]  {
        geoip {
          source => "dest_ip"
          target => "geoip"
          #database => "/opt/logstash/vendor/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat"
          add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
          add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
        }
        mutate {
          convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

30-lumberjack-output.conf

```
output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

logstash fordwarer conf

```
"files": [
   {
      "paths": [
        "/var/log/syslog",
        "/var/log/auth.log"
       ],
      "fields": { "type": "syslog" }
    },
    # An array of hashes. Each hash tells what paths to watch and
    # what fields to annotate on events from those paths.
    #{
      #"paths": [
        # single paths are fine
        #"/var/log/messages",
        # globs are fine too, they will be periodically evaluated
        # to see if any new files match the wildcard.
        #"/var/log/*.log"
      #],

      # A dictionary of fields to annotate on each event.
      #"fields": { "type": "syslog" }
    #}, {
      # A path of "-" means stdin.
      #"paths": [ "-" ],
      #"fields": { "type": "stdin" }
#    },
      {
      "paths": [
        "/var/log/apache2/*.log"
      ],
      "fields": { "type": "apache-access" }
        },
        {
      "paths": [
        "/var/log/auth*.log"
      ],
      "fields": { "type": "sshlog" }
        }
        "files": [
    {
      "paths": [ "/var/log/suricata/eve.json" ],
      "fields": { "type": "suricata" }
    }

  ]


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to install suricata on both servers and make a few configuration changes to get the data to post JSON

Barring that everything that was posted above was all that was needed